# Custom Splash Screen: Image not Rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, splash-screen

I'm trying to create a Custom Spalsh Screen in WPF - Net 4.8 - C# to show a startup image with some messages that change during Loading process.

The Spalsh screen is in a separete Library. Here my code:

SPLASH SCREEN LIBRARY:

1. Window (xaml):

```
<Window ... 
        Title="SplashScreenWindow" Height="400" Width="610" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" >
    <StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="imgSplash" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding ConfigModel.DisplayedImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

2. Window (cs):

```
public SplashScreenWindow(string SplashImagePath)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = new MySplashScreenViewModel(SplashImagePath);
}
```

SplashImagePath is the path to the Image. It is passed to the ViewModel. If it is null, default image should be loaded.

3. ViewModel:

```
    public class SplashScreenConfigModel : ConfigModelBase
    {

        public BitmapImage DisplayedImage
        {
            get { return GetValue(() => this.DisplayedImage); }
            set { SetValue(() => this.DisplayedImage, value);}
        }

    }

    public class MySplashScreenViewModel : PropertyChangedNotificationBase
    {
        public MySplashScreenConfigModel ConfigModel
        {
            get { return GetValue(() => this.ConfigModel); }
            set { SetValue(() => this.ConfigModel, value); }
        }

        public MySplashScreenViewModel(string SplashImagePath)
        {
            ConfigModel = new SplashScreenConfigModel();

            if (SplashImagePath.IsEmpty()) SplashImagePath = "Media/DefaultImage.png";
            ConfigModel.DisplayedImage = ImagesUtilities.LoadBitmapImageFromPath(SplashImagePath);
        }
    }
```

where MyImagesUtilities.LoadBitmapImageFromPath(SplashImagePath) is coded like that:

```
public static BitmapImage LoadBitmapImageFromPath(string path)
        {
            if (path.IsEmpty()) return null;
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            img.DecodePixelWidth = 610;

            img.BeginInit();
            img.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
            img.EndInit();
            return img;
        }
```

MAIN APP

The OnStartup is coded Like that:

```
       protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            SplashScreenWindow splash = new SplashScreenWindow("Media/AppImage.png");
            this.MainWindow = splash;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                splash.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => splash.Show());

                //Various activities...

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                    this.MainWindow = main;
                    main.Show();

                    splash.Close();
                }));
            });

        }

    }
```

When I start the app, the splash screen appears, but no image is shown.

But if I:

1. Put a breakpoint at the end of the SetSplashScreen method
   [breakpoint at the end of the SetSplashScreen method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niCqt.jpg)
2. Insert img.Height in the watches:
   [img.Height in watches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fv7S.png)

And the I run the app, and, when breakpoint, is reached, click on "Continue", first one of this two errors occur:

[Exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJXs2.png)

or

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJJmS.png)

But after, by clicking again on Continue, the Splash Screen appears with the correct Image.
[Correct Splash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juEoO.png)

Images (both deafult and app image) are a .png images with Compile Action = "Content" and Copy in output directory = "Copy if newer".

How can I correct that? Any idea?

Comment: Note that `img.DecodePixelWidth = 610;` before `img.BeginInit();` has no effect.

Comment: Besides that, if the image is part of your Visual Studio project, it should be provided as assembly resource file. Set its Build Action to Resource, do not copy to the output directory, and load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8): `BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" +  path));`

Comment: Thanks a lot Clemens! I modified as you suggested both points. In particular for the second, I used `"pack://application:,,,/Media/AppImage.png"` in the `OnStartup()` method, and `"pack://application:,,,/MyCommonComponents;component/Media/DefaultImage.png"` in the external library MySplashScreenViewModel method. Finally I modified `img.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);`, setting UriKind to `RelativeOrAbsolute`, instead of `Relative`. Now it works perfectly.